# Easy way to make domain.com/wp-admin/ for all sites on a server accessible only for localhost?

Tags: ssh, .htaccess, wordpress

I have problems with attacks to those so thought best would be to limit the access for them only to locahost. 
But what will be the best (and easy) way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is not necessarily restricting wp-admin to localhost, but an ip filter.
This is a common solution to brute force attacks.
However depending on what you're experiencing, there are many approaches.

[You might want to read the WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Brute_Force_Attacks) (go to Limit Access to wp-admin by IP)

Comment: My IP changes a lot so I want to do what I said I want to do.
But I guess what you offered can be put to use for my need by using "localhost" in the .htaccess file instead of an IP? :)

Comment: @user240891 you can also define an ip range. Your ip usually does not deviate much after new assignments.